# Find the first four nonzero terms in each of two power series solutions about the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I just started in differential equation. I ran into some trouble with a problem in an exercise.

The problems goes:

Find the first four nonzero terms in each of two power series solutions about the origin.

$e^xy'' + xy = 0$

since $e^x$ is analytic at every real number, thus I know the power series solution exist at $x=0$

But I do not know how to find them. Hence I was hoping using this question as an example, perhaps someone could give me a general steps/guide to solve similar questions?

P.S: This exercise is from the book Elementary differential equation and Boundary problem.

Thank you in advance for any help given

Answer (score 1):

Let $y(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kx^k$, then
$$y''(x)=\sum_{k\geq 2}k(k-1)a_kx^{k-2}=\sum_{k\geq 0}(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}x^{k}=2a_2+6a_3 x+12a_4 x^2+o(x^2).$$
Moreover 
$$e^x=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3).$$

Plug all these series in $e^xy''(x) + xy(x)$. The coefficients of resulting series should be all zero.

We have that the first few terms of the expansion are:
$$e^xy''(x) + xy(x)=2a_2+(6a_3+2a_2+a_0)x+(12a_4+6a_3+a_2+a_1)x^2+o(x^2)$$
which implies that 
$$\mbox{$a_2=0$, $6a_3+2a_2+a_0=0$, $12a_4+6a_3+a_2+a_1=0$.}$$
The coefficients $a_n$ are not uniquely determined because the differential equation admits infinite solutions.

Comment: Since it is a second order differential equation, you can keep $a_0$ and $a_1$ undefined and express all the other as linear combinations of them. I suppose that would give $$y=a_0+a_1 x-\frac{1}{6} a_0 x^3+\frac{1}{12} (a_0-a_1) x^4+\frac{1}{40} (2
   a_1-a_0) x^5+\cdots$$ The problem now is : what are the initil conditions ? This could require much more terms, I bet.

Comment: Just suppose the conditions to be $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=0$; this will make =a_0=a_1=0$ which end to ... nowhere, may be. Cheers.